# GTK How to set font for a text_view

Tags: c, gtk3

How can I set the font name and size for a text_view? Or do I have to set the font information at the buffer or at the window? Do I have to create some sort of style-sheet?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *view;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    view = gtk_text_view_new();

    buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(view));

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 350, 300);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), view);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The following code works.

my.c

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkWidget *view;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer;
    GtkWidget *window;

    GdkDisplay *display;
    GdkScreen *screen;
    GtkCssProvider *provider;

    GError *error;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    view = gtk_text_view_new();
    buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(view));

    display = gdk_display_get_default ();
    screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen (display);
    provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (screen, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

    error = NULL;
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_file (provider, g_file_new_for_path("my.css"), &error);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 350, 300);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), view);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

my.css

```
GtkTextView
{
    font:Monospace 10;
}.
```

Comment: This makes it indeed very very complicated from the developer view. I liked the deprecated functions instead.

Answer (score 4):

I know it is 2 years old question but in case someone encounter any issues. 
Note, that Pango syntax for the font is deprecated in Gtk+3.

If you want to use GtkSourceView:

```
#include <gtksourceview/gtksource.h>
```

must be installed separately and compiled with

```
`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtksourceview-3.0`
```

or use regular GtkTextView

```
 GtkCssProvider *cssProvider;
 GtkSourceView *view;
 GError *error = NULL;
 GtkStyleContext *context;

 /* new css provider */
 cssProvider = gtk_css_provider_new(); 

 view = GTK_SOURCE_VIEW(gtk_source_view_new ());

 /* widget name for css syntax */
 gtk_widget_set_name (GTK_WIDGET(view), "cssView");   

 /* load css file */
 gtk_css_provider_load_from_path (cssProvider, "main.css", &error); 

 /* get GtkStyleContext from widget   */
 context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(GTK_WIDGET(view));  

 /* finally load style provider */
 gtk_style_context_add_provider(context,    
                             GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(cssProvider), 
                             GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
```

and "main.css" file in the same directory

```
#cssView { 
      font: 15px "Monospace";
      color: #ff0000;          /*in case you need red color*/
}
```

Actually in Gtk+3 you can add and remove CSS classes in very easy way:

in one callback you need to call:

```
 gtk_style_context_add_class(context, "redFonts");
```

then in another one:

```
 gtk_style_context_remove_class(context, "redFonts");
```

your "main.css" should be like:

```
#tab1Content {
    font: 15px "Monospace";
}
.redFonts{
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: This makes me a bit sad. Not that CSS becomes more important, mind you - CSS is actually one of the things I like. But that setting fonts is so ... complicated. My use case originates from ruby-gtk2 still (even though ruby-gtk3 exists); and my old way was ::Gtk::Settings.default.gtk_font_name =, which unfortunately changes fonts globally, so I wanted a per-widget solution instead (it makes sense to use mono-spaced font for a code editor, for example). I never imagined things be so complicated. This actually makes the www stack so much more convenient compared to this. :(

Comment: I noticed that the priority-trick was actually given in a forum discussion (the SO here was linked in from that forum discussion); this answer is interesting then. We could decide that per-css rules have a higher priority over themes, right? E. g. the part here: GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION

Comment: This makes it indeed very very complicated from the developer view. I liked the deprecated functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

Some comment to the previous answers suggested that "Pango syntax for the font is deprecated in Gtk+3". I'm not sure about what exactly that is was referring to, but Pango markup syntax  *is* supported in GTK 3 and 4.
Using Pango markup embedded in the string is the easiest way to set size and other font attributes. No need to do anything with CSS. For example, in Python you can do:

```
label = Gtk.Label()
label.set_markup("<span font='100'>A BIG title - and the Author's name</span>")
```

[Pango Documentation](https://docs.gtk.org/Pango/pango_markup.html)